# Not Showing Results in SearchView & RecyclerView / CardView

Tags: android, searchview

I've added a SearchView to my application, the only problem is it's not showing up results, i may know why, because it's not linked with the generated new items ( new items ), or maybe something else i dunno about .

Here are the files :

Adapter :

```
public class RecyclingViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclingViewAdapter.MyRecycleViewHolder>{

//Booleans for Expand & Favorite Buttons Visibility
boolean expand_visibility = true;

//Booleans favorite Buttons
boolean fav_button = true;

//Settings ItemsData List & Recycling Info
List<itemsdata> data = Collections.emptyList();

private final LayoutInflater inflater;
public RecyclingViewAdapter adapter;

public RecyclingViewAdapter(Context context,List<itemsdata> data)
{
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public MyRecycleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent,false);
    MyRecycleViewHolder MyHolder = new MyRecycleViewHolder(view);
    return MyHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyRecycleViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //Referencing Data
    final itemsdata currentobject = data.get(position);
    //Referencing Items
    holder.ProbTitle.setText(currentobject.title);
    holder.ProbDescr.setText(currentobject.Descr);
    holder.CategoryPic.setImageResource(currentobject.CatPic);
    holder.ExpandButton.setImageResource(currentobject.Exapnd);
    holder.ExpandNoButton.setImageResource(currentobject.expand_no);

    //Swipe Layout Codes
    holder.swipeLayout.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.PullOut);
    // Drag From Right
    holder.swipeLayout.addDrag(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Right, holder.swipeLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_wrapper));
    // Handling different events when swiping
    holder.swipeLayout.addSwipeListener(new SwipeLayout.SwipeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClose(SwipeLayout layout) {
            //when the SurfaceView totally cover the BottomView.
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(SwipeLayout layout, int leftOffset, int topOffset) {
            //you are swiping.
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {
            //when the BottomView totally show.
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartClose(SwipeLayout layout) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onHandRelease(SwipeLayout layout, float xvel, float yvel) {
            //when user's hand released.
        }
    });


    holder.swipeLayout.getSurfaceView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });

    /*
    //What Happen When You Press "Star" Text .
    holder.Card_Star.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (fav_button) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Starred!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                holder.Card_Star.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.Card_UnStar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fav_button = false;
            }
        }
    });

    //What Happen When You Re-Press "Star" Text .
    holder.Card_UnStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (fav_button == false) {
                holder.Card_UnStar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.Card_Star.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                fav_button = true;
            }
        }
    });
    */
    //What Happen When You Press "Share" Text .
    holder.Card_Share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String shareQ = view.getContext().getString(R.string.ShareQ);
            String shareA = view.getContext().getString(R.string.ShareA);
            String shareinfo = view.getContext().getString(R.string.ShareInfo);
            String sharetitle = currentobject.title;
            String sharedescription = currentobject.Descr;
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("text/plain");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    shareQ + " " + sharetitle
                    + "\n"
                    + "\n"
                    + shareA + " " + sharedescription
                    + "\n"
                    + "\n"
                    + shareinfo
                    );
            view.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share The Answer"));
        }
    });

    //What Happen When You Click Expand Button .
    holder.ExpandButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (expand_visibility) {
                //Set Expand Button To Gone
                holder.ExpandButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //Set Description To Visible
                holder.ProbDescr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //Set UnExpand To Button Visible
                holder.ExpandNoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                expand_visibility = false;
            }
        }
    });

    //What Happen When You Click UnExpand Button
    holder.ExpandNoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (expand_visibility == false) {
                //Set Description To Gone
                holder.ProbDescr.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //Set UnExpand Button To Gone
                holder.ExpandNoButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //Set Expand Button To Visible
                holder.ExpandButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                expand_visibility = true;
            }

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public static class MyRecycleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    SwipeLayout swipeLayout;
    //Defining Items .
    TextView ProbTitle;
    ImageButton ExpandButton;
    TextView ProbDescr;
    ImageButton ExpandNoButton;
    ImageView CategoryPic;
    /*
    TextView Card_Star;
    TextView Card_UnStar;
    */
    TextView Card_Share;

    //Referencing Resources
    public MyRecycleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ProbTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.prob_title);
        CategoryPic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_pic);
        ProbDescr = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.prob_descr);
        ExpandButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.expand_button);
        ExpandNoButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.expand_no_button);
        /*
        Card_Star = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_star);
        Card_UnStar = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_unstar);
        */
        Card_Share = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_share);
        swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
    }

}

public void setFilter(List<itemsdata> searchingdata) {
    data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.addAll(searchingdata);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

Tab_1 ( I'm using SlidingTabLayout, So this is the fragment of the tab 1 )

```
public class tab_1 extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

private List<itemsdata> msearchingdata;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
public RecyclingViewAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)layout.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    adapter = new RecyclingViewAdapter(getActivity(),getData());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return layout;

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,
            new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                    // Do something when collapsed
                    adapter.setFilter(msearchingdata);
                    return true; // Return true to collapse action view
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                    // Do something when expanded
                    return true; // Return true to expand action view
                }
            });
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    final List<itemsdata> filteredModelList = filter(msearchingdata, newText);
    adapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

private List<itemsdata> filter(List<itemsdata> current2, String query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();

    final List<itemsdata> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (itemsdata model : current2) {
        final String text = model.getText().toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(query)) {
            filteredModelList.add(model);
        }
    }
    return filteredModelList;
}

public List<itemsdata> getData()
{
    //Titles Strings
    String sys_title1 = getString(R.string.system_item_title_1);
    String sys_title2 = getString(R.string.system_item_title_2);
    String sys_title3 = getString(R.string.system_item_title_3);

    //Description Strings
    String sys_descr1 = getString(R.string.system_item_desc_1);
    String sys_descr2 = getString(R.string.system_item_desc_2);
    String sys_descr3 = getString(R.string.system_item_desc_3);

    //Adding New Cards
    List<itemsdata> data = new ArrayList<>();

    //Categories Icons New Items ** Make It The Same
    int[] icons = {
            R.drawable.facebook_icon ,
            R.drawable.twitter_icon ,
            R.drawable.twitter_icon
    };

    //Expand Button New Items
    int[] expandbutton = {
            R.drawable.expanded ,
            R.drawable.expanded ,
            R.drawable.expanded
    };

    //UnExpand Button New Items
    int[] unexpandbutton = {
            R.drawable.ca_expand ,
            R.drawable.ca_expand ,
            R.drawable.ca_expand
    };

    //Titles New Items
    String[] titles = {
            sys_title1 ,
            sys_title2 ,
            sys_title3
    };

    //Description New Items
    String[] Description = {
            sys_descr1 ,
            sys_descr2 ,
            sys_descr3
    };


    for(int i = 0;i<titles.length && i < icons.length  && i < Description.length ; i++)
    {
        itemsdata current = new itemsdata();
        current.CatPic = icons[i];
        current.title = titles[i];
        current.Descr = Description[i];
        data.add(current);
    }
    return data;
}


}
```

My itemsdata :

```
public class itemsdata {
int CatPic;
String title;
String Descr;
int Exapnd;
int expand_no;

public String getText() {
    return title;
}

}
```

As you can see, it's not linked with the new items, and i don't know how i'm gonna do that .
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not the right way to code this much and wondering why all your code doesnt work, make a new adapter, go step by step to see what you are doing wrong. It will take atleast 10 mins to debug this code even for a pro.

Comment: Only code added to Adapter and related to the search is "setFilter" so i don't think it's related to it, right ?

Comment: It is really hard to say what is causing the problem, the only suggestion i can give is to start from scratch and see what is causing the problem.

Comment: @AshkanGhodrat the available methods about SearchView with RecyclerView are different, Plus there is no Tip/Tutorial about CardView SearchView.
Plus, the problem is only in the Filtering Codes, the search bar is working well, but what ever the text you put, it won't filter the View .